# How to do a global replace on backslash in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I've tried: (Incase all the slashes make it hard to read, 1st line should replace forward slashes, 2nd line should replace backslashes, 3rd line should replace asterisks.

```
newbigbend = bb_val.replace(/\//gi,"");
newbigbend = bb_val.replace(/\\/gi,"");
newbigbend = bb_val.replace(/*/gi,"");
```

to replace all forward slashes, backslashes and asterisks. But when the browser gets to the middle line `newbigbend = bb_val.replace(/\\/gi,"");` it thinks its an unterminated comment. I know to use the escape to replace the forward slash. Not sure about back.

Comment: What does bb_val contain? What do you want it to be?

Comment: You could do this with one regex instead of three: `/[\/\\\*]/`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Andrew Cooper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854352/how-to-do-a-global-replace-on-backslash-in-a-string-in-javascipt/5854429#5854429) is correct in terms of why that third statement is going wrong. But you're also overwriting `newbigbend` each time, so you won't see the result of the first two replacements at all.

If you're trying to replace all slashes, backslashes, and asterisks with nothing, do this:

```
newbigbend = bb_val.replace(/[/\\*]/g, "");
```

Note you don't need the `i` flag, none of those characters is case sensitive anyway. (And note that within the `[]`, you don't need to escape `/` or `*`, because they don't have special meaning there.) [Live example](http://jsbin.com/ulore4).

But if you want it as three individual statements for whatever reason, then use `newbigbend` in the second two (and add the backslash Andrew flagged up):

```
newbigbend = bb_val.replace(/\//gi,"");
newbigbend = newbigbend.replace(/\\/gi,"");
newbigbend = newbigbend.replace(/\*/gi,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to escape the `*`

```
newbigbend = bb_val.replace(/\*/gi,"");
```